# Photo Size and Resolution for iOS app

Tags: ios, resolution, photo

I am working on an iOS application that will show photos either in full screen or in frames in various sizes - like product catalog.

I know I am supposed to use images.xcassets to make things simple and I know I am supposed to create more than one version of the same photo in different sizes.

All I can find is AppIcon and LaunchImage guidelines. What would be the rules I should follow preparing photos to show in different devices? Sizes, resolutions?
Sample: I have 2048 x 1536 raw sized photo (even bigger ones). When it comes to prepare it for iOS app (will work both in iPad and iPhone), what are the dimensions to export my photos from PhotoShop? What would be the biggest sized version?

Could someone please show me a starting point to understand this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This design guidelines](http://iosdesign.ivomynttinen.com/) guide is very good. You will find everything you have to know about sizes.
[image]

But the simplest way is to use a tool like [Asset Catalog Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/asset-catalog-creator-free/id866571115?mt=12) to generate your assets. Just drop your original image in it, select your @1x size, and it will generate the catalog for you, for all sizes.

Comment: Thank you , Quentin. I am looking at the Resolutions and Display Specifications in the page you posted. Let me sample to ask: for example iPhone6 and iPad Retina: iPhone6 is 1080 x 1920 and iPad Retina is 1536 x 2048. Considering these numbers, should I create 2 version of the same photo in these dimensions? Is this the idea?

Comment: Yes. Or use the tool I linked at the end of my answer. It will do the work for you.

Comment: one more related question while I got you: What resolution (pixels/inch) I should use when I export from PhotoShop?
I understand the tool, but I like to do it manually first to understand what's going on. So I learn and likely use the tools when I am confident that I know what's going on.

Comment: Export as big as you can. The tool will resize in the best resolution for your needs. And you might want to use the original big resolution on future devices for example.

Comment: ok, I am really impressed with the tool. I should learn about the resolution still but thank you for the heads up about this application :)

Comment: Just a little question before we leave this conversation back: iPhone 6 and iPad Retina, they are not same width / height (aspect ratio) and let's say I need to crop a photo to use for iPad what I already used for iPhone, I can sacrifice from the cropped portion let's say. In this case, I should put the image into the asset catalog manually, am I getting it right?

Comment: I am using the tool and all fine for organizing the images - which actually can be done also via xCode. However, I use the tool and get 5 MB PNG file, on the other hand, same resolution, a little bit quality loss but JPG file added xCode manually, takes 300KB! Consider 100% quality, then it takes only 800KB! This is very important because I will put many many images in the bundle, perhaps 50-60 images. I think I will go and create a photoshop action that does this for me. It looks to me the JPG is way to go. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [screen size reference](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) for iPhone devices you may find helpful. Here's one [for iPads](http://www.iosres.com).

Additionally, if you've got a lot of files you need to resize that you've already exported, you might consider using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for batch resizing.